# Enums: set members values equal to their names, bad practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

Since one can create an Enum member values of any Data Type: [Creating an Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum)

> **Note: Enum member values**
> Member values can be anything: int, str, etc.. If the exact value is unimportant you may use auto instances and an appropriate value will be chosen for you. Care must be taken if you mix auto with other values.

Sometimes, I see repeating members values of type `str` :

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = "RED"
    GREEN = "GREEN"
    BLUE = "BLUE"
```

Is it considered as a bad practice to repeat members names with values of type `str` ?

Comment: It's not bad practice in general. Specific context would be needed to determine if it's being misused or not.

Comment: It's fine, an `Enum` member isn't the same thing as a string (and has its own unique abilities/properties/attributes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value in your enum is not important, then the type of the value is also not important -- it can be whatever you want.

As far as ease-of-use goes, typing `auto()` is probably easier.

Comment: NassimH: Be advised that Ethan is principle author of `Enum`s — so you should  consider this literally to be an authoritative answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think so. The reason you want to use `Enum` in the first place is that it's something you couldn't "accidentally" compare to. If you set the member values to `"RED"` then I think you would accidentally return `True` if you compared `Color.RED == "RED"`. And this basically defeats the purpose of an `Enum` in the first place (as in, why not just always use strings `'RED'`, `'BLUE'`, etc.)

If what you want is for your `Enum` to print a representative string, just override the `___str___` to do so:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The accidental comparison thing isn't really why we use enums, and [`Color.RED == "RED"` produces `False`](https://ideone.com/jW9pzf).

Comment: We don't use enums because we want `Color.RED != "RED"`. The biggest reason to use enums is because we want `Color.RAD` to raise an error. Other reasons include things like clearly communicating allowed values. Using `RED = "RED"` doesn't interfere with these reasons.